# How many satisfying assignments are there in a set of 3-CNF clauses where no clause share the same variable?

Tags: combinatorics, boolean-algebra, satisfiability

Say I have a set of 3-CNF clauses
$$\mathcal{S} = \{ x_1 \vee x_2 \vee \bar{x_3}, ~~x_4 \vee x_5 \vee x_6\}$$

where $\bar{x}$ is the negation of $x$. Each variable range over $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

How many satisfying assginments are there for $S$? In general, how many satisfying assignments are there for $S$ is the size of $S$ is k?

This is a question about what is a satisfying assignment for 3-disjunctive clause as much as it is about counting. For example when I just have $C = x_1 \vee x_2 \vee \bar{x_3}$, there are $2^3 = 8$ possible assignments:
$$1 1 1\\
0 1 1 \\
1 0 1\\
1 1 0\\
1 0 0\\
0 1 0\\
0 0 1\\
0 0 0
$$
But which one of these are satisfying assignments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each clause has exactly one way of being false...

Comment: so for all possible clauses formed with $x_1,x_2,x_3$ and their negations, that is we would have $2^3$ possible clauses, there are exactly one way in which each clause is wrong? So in total there are $(2^3 - 1)\cdot(2^3)$ satisfying assignments over all possible disjunctions of the three $x_j$'s?

Comment: No, you are overcounting. If you look at all possible clauses formed with $x_1,x_2,x_3$ and their negations, no single assignment can satisfy all of them, and every assignment satisfies most of them.

Comment: ops, the multiplication was not needed. But still there are $2^3$ possible ways to form a clause with three variables, and for $each$ possible clause there are $2^3 - 1$ satisfying assignments, correct? So $fixing$ a set $S$ of k disjoint clauses, there are then $k \cdot (2^3-1)$ satisfying assignments.